# Soft keyboard not popping up when edit text has focus on Genymotion device

Tags: android, genymotion

In my application there is a search segment -- just like on the twitter app. When the user clicks the magnifying glass the search segment starts (a fragment) and the keyboard is suppose to pop up so the user can type the query into the search bar.

What actually happens is the cursor is blinking in the search bar, and I can type into the bar with the hard keyboard, but the soft keyboard doesn't pop up. If I click the search bar, then the soft keyboard pops up.

Any ideas why the soft keyboard isn't popping up when the cursor is blinking in the search bar?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the soft keyboard isn't enabled by default on Genymotion.

I've turned on the soft keyboard by going to Settings | Language & Input | Current Keyboard and turning on the Show Input Method switch.  But I have had some difficulty with this.

Different API versions have different UIs for this setting and it's never quite clear how to get the soft keys to show.  Sometimes I've set the soft keys to show and they still don't show.  Maybe you have to set them then restart Android on the device.

But that's where the setting is, and if your experience is anything like mine, you'll get it soft keys to show after you jank around with it for awhile.

Answer (score -1):

You must enable it from the Genymotion application:

- Open Genymotion app, it will display the list of your Genymotion devices
- On the device you want to use the virtual keyboard click on the setting icon

[image: Genymotion setting icon]

- Then check the option "Use virtual keyboard for text input"

You will then have a virtual keyboard poping up when you click on an edit text.

This will work whatever the Android version of your device is.

Comment: The soft keyboard doesn't pop up unless this option is checked, and I already said that the soft keyboard does pop up